# How to read and echo Specific Line in text file

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. Can someone show me an example of how to read a specific line of a file and echo it with PHP?

For example I have a file called *note.txt*:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

From this file I only want to read and echo line2 till line5.

Thank you before for all the answer

Comment: Well if you tried something.. We could help you better.. But let's say you did try something.. Then you could keep a counter for each line you read and say to echo line 2 and 5.

Comment: i only know how to read whole line in a file with php, but dont know how to get it in specific line

Comment: i only know this way to read a file with php <br><br><?php
 $f = fopen("http://example.com/note.txt", "r");
 // Read line by line until end of file
 while(!feof($f)) { 
     echo fgets($f);
 }
 fclose($f);
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Unless the file has a significant size, you can use the function [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for this. `file()` will return the lines of a file as an array.

Example:

```
$start = 1; // array indexes are starting with zero
$end = 4;   // array indexes are starting with zero

$lines = file('filename'); // get lines of file as an array
for($i = $start; $i <= $end && $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    echo $lines[$i];
}
```

However, if the file has a significant size the code above will consume much memory (~as much as the file's size) because `file()` will read the whole file into an array. If you are working with large files, you can use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and iterate over the file's lines using [`fgets()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) unless you reach the start line, read to the end line and finally close the file:

```
$ln = 0;
$start = 1;
$end = 4;  

$fd = fopen(__FILE__, 'r'); // open the file

while(true) {
    $line = fgets($fd); // read next line
    if(!$line ||  $ln === $end + 1) {
        break;
    }
    if($ln >= $start && $ln <= $end) {
        echo $line;
    }
    $ln++;
}

fclose($fd); // close the file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

example :

```
$myFile = "tmp.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
echo $lines[1]; //line 2
```

you need to make loop from 2 -> 5 to get all this lines